# Tutorial code is not working any more in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla-component

I followed a tutorial from the Joomla developer wiki (http://docs.joomla.org/Developers#Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_.28MVC.29_Component_2) to create a Joomla component. It all worked fine in Joomla 1.7, but when I upgraded to Joomla 2.5 the checkboxes in the backend are not working any more.

I checked the code from http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!1.7_-_Part_09#Adding_a_toolbar in Joomla 2.5 extensions and the boxchecked hidden field is still there. Also the javascript around is still the same.

Does anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The form should have a id next to the name. Joomla 1.7 is only checking on the name, but Joomla 2.5 is checking for the id.

Comment: can you post details of the specific file and change you had to make to correct the issue?

Answer (score 1):

visit this weblink, it might be useful to you..

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_13#Articles_in_this_series