# Joomla checkbox doesn't update database

Tags: php, joomla, checkbox, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and have a problem while fooling aroung with my first component.

I use the following fieldset in a form:

```
<fieldset>      
    <field
        name="person_id"
        type="hidden"
    />
    <field
        name="person_email"
        type="text"
        label="Email"
        description="Email"
        size="40"
        class="inputbox"
        default=""
    />
    <field
        name="person_notification"
        type="text"
        label="Notification"
        description="Notification"
        class="checkbox"
    />
</fieldset>
```

The email field is working as expected and updates the database entry. The notification field is making me trouble. The value is not set.

I have read about this issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/wc3ns5NucM8) and [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Talk:Checkbox_form_field_type). I tried to adapt the method 2 from the second link, but it didn't help me. The code I tried was:

```
<fieldset>      
    <field
        name="person_id"
        type="hidden"
    />
    <field
        name="person_email"
        type="text"
        label="Email"
        description="Email"
        size="40"
        class="inputbox"
        default=""
    />
    <input type="hidden" name="jform[person_notification]" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="person_notification" class="inputbox" />
</fieldset>
```

The checkbox is not visible at all  in this case, because in my edit.php I use

```
<?php foreach($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): 
   if ($field->label!="") {
       echo '<li>'.$field->label.$field->input.'<br/></li>';
   } else {
       echo '<li>'.$field->input.'</li>';             
   }?>
```

So I think I have to adapt method 2 to use `field` tags, but I don't know how to do this. Can anybody tell me, how I have to define my filedset to get this working? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725937/joomla-php-checkbox-wont-uncheck?rq=1) SO question, but I am not sure, whether this is exactly the problem I am experiencing.

I am aware of the possibility to use radio buttons, but my requirements don't allow this workaround. Changing anything in the core joomla code or updating to version 3 is also no valid possibility in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but have you tried removing the white spaces? So try changing this : `name = "person_notification"` to this `name="person_notification"`

Comment: @Lodder No, unfortunately this doesn't change anything.

Comment: What about the solution suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11613965/268093)? It uses a `<field>` in the `XML` and overrides the model's `bind()` method to handle the case where the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong.

Try replicating the functionality using the Joomla Component Creator http://www.component-creator.com and see what the difference is.

Comment: @MasterAM I had tried this and it did not work. I tried a minimal example with the creator and it worked.. And it seems, it generated exactly what I tried before.. Must have made a mistake. Thanks to you both. Would have never tried this approach again on my own, because I thought it was wrong.

Comment: the Joomla checkbox will only return a value if the checkbox is checked, and you need to work around this in your code; this is why so many extensions use type="list" with the options values set to 0 and 1. Try changing it to the list type, add two options and see if your code works as expected, this will be a quick workaround.